# How to count how many shell/terminals are running?

Tags: bash, ps

I´m trying to count how many shell or terminal windows are currently running.

I tried `ps a|grep bash;` `ps a|grep tty;`

But it can be inaccurate.

Comment: What's your definition of _terminal window_? Do a gnome-terminal tab, virtual terminal, person logging in over ssh, screen/tmux pane, `expect` emulated user session, `xterm` not running a shell, etc count?

Comment: Terminal window opened with "ctrl-alt-t".

I solved it by counting how many "pts" are in >who command

**who|grep "pts"|wc -l**

Answer (score 10):

```
ls /dev/pts/  | wc -l
```

Use the above command to count the terminal windows open.

Comment: Tried that. It shows 23. And I have only one terminal/bash window open.

Comment: @user68957 Are you on a shared computer with multiple users by any chance?

Comment: One home computer, one user at the time.  
The trick would be to count how many terminal windows are open, or terminal processes.  
  
If I do a >who, it list two users  
  
me :0     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm (:0)  
me pts/0  yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm (:0)  
  
If I open another terminal window, with >who it shows:  
  
  
me :0     yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm (:0)  
me pts/0  yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm (:0)  
me pts/1  yyyy-mm-dd hh-mm (:0)  
  
Should I just grep "pts/"?

Answer (score 4):

To list them:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v "?"
```

To count them:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v "?" | wc -l
```

You will need to subtract 1 from that number as it includes the top TTY header.

This all depends if you are wanting to count how many sub shells are running or if you are wanting to count how many terminal windows are open.

To count just the terminal windows you would need to use:

```
ls /dev/pts/ | wc -l (stated in a previous answer)
```

For example:

On my system there are currently six tty's available. I also have one terminal open pts/0 that has 4 processes running in the fg or bg.

```
root      4565  0.0  0.0   4060   576 tty1     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty1
root      4567  0.0  0.0   4060   572 tty2     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty2
root      4569  0.0  0.0   4060   568 tty3     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty3
root      4571  0.0  0.0   4060   576 tty4     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty4
root      4573  0.0  0.0   4060   576 tty5     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty5
root      4575  0.0  0.0   4060   572 tty6     Ss+  May01   0:00 /sbin/mingetty /dev/tty6

me  17482  0.0  0.0 110236  1136      pts/0    R+   11:36   0:00 ps aux
root     20374  0.0  0.0 108336  1816 pts/0    Ss   May23   0:00 -bash
root     20953  0.0  0.1 161436  1960 pts/0    S    May23   0:00 su - me
me  20954  0.0  0.1 108524  1984      pts/0    S    May23   0:00 -bash
```

If you want to take away the background child processes then just pipe to uniq:

```
ps aux | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v "?" | uniq | wc -l
```

You still have to subtract 1 for the header title of TTY, but you can further improve this by taking the tty's out altogether as it appears you don't care about those anyways.

```
ps aux | awk '{print $7}' | grep -v "?" | grep -vi "tty*" | uniq
```

That will give you an accurate count.

**EDIT**

Thinking about it more 'ps -a' would work better and you can leave out the first grep.

```
ps a | awk '{print $2}' | grep -vi "tty*" | uniq | wc -l
```

Comment: `grep` and `awk` is redundant, use `awk '/pattern/`; and this doesn't work on my machine - it reports 19 when I have 1.

Comment: I am a bit confused. Right now, I´m on Ubuntu 14. 
There is only one terminal/bash window open. 

With the abobe commands, I get 23 or 13, when I should get 1, or 2 in case I open another terminal with ctrl-alt-t

Comment: That first command counts children processes running in shells in the background and not just open terminal sessions

Comment: @jasonwryan - It works just fine on mine. Using grep with awk is person preference. If someone is more comfortable doing the whole thing in awk then that's fine.

Comment: "It works just fine on mine" hardly substantiates your answer... Perhaps you could include some detail of what "yours" is so people are aware that it only applies to that system.

Comment: Umm...did you even read my really long edit to my answer?

Comment: To filter out the header, use the pattern matching in awk.  `ps aux | awk '/tty[0-9]/ { print $7 } | uniq | wc -l`

Comment: Sorry to reply to my own comment. My edits timed out. If the tty numbers are duplicated and mixed, in the results, then uniq doesn't work. Add a `sort` command in there, just before uniq.

Answer (score 0):

On macos you can use:

```
cnt=$(w -h | grep "^$(whoami) *s[^ ]* *-"|wc -l)
echo "Your current terminal sessions: $cnt"
```

Found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/6180547/6320039

Answer (score -1):

You could do `$ pgrep bash`

[image]

Also you can do `$ W`

[image]

Answer (score -1):

You can add the `\l` option in your PS1 variable, example:

```
export PS1="terminal #\l \W \$ "
```

That will count your terminals starting from zero.

More about it in the [GNU website](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Controlling-the-Prompt.html).

Hope this helps.

Comment: The doco that you point to tells you that it does not count anything.

Comment: "The basename of the shell’s terminal device name."
That's what it says, I tried it myself and (in practice) it shows the terminal number starting from 0, and if you are inside a tty (no gui) it will tell you which tty you are in.